# How to change subject of email in prestashop

Tags: email, gmail, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to change the subject of email in Prestashop " i need to delete the [] brackets punctuation mark "

Now email is: [myshop_Name] Order confirmation

What i need: myshop_Name Order confirmation

I would be thankfull for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
edit the mail.php which is under classes by deleting the brackets  []:
$subject = '['.Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME', null, null, $idShop).'] '.$subject;